# Does every Vector space have at least one linearly independent subset?

Tags: vector-spaces

It might sound like a strange question to ask, but I want to know because I'm trying to prove that every infinite dimensional vector space V has a basis. The proof consists of considering the set of all linearly independent subsets of V, together with set-inclusion relation. The first step would have to be to show that this set is non-empty. Is there a trivial subset that is linearly independent or is it impossible to say? How would I argue that the set of linearly independent subsets is non-empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Just take a single non-zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is linearly independent: no vector in it is a linear combination of the other elements in the set (because there's no element to begin with).

And indeed it's a basis of the trivial vector space. You want to show that every vector space has a basis: so also the trivial vector space must.

If you're afraid of the empty set (but you shouldn't), prove the statement for nontrivial vector spaces. Such a space has a nonzero vector $v$ and $\{v\}$ is linearly independent.